# How to properly address a modified Django login form in the template files using crispy forms?

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a modified Django login form and I have to address it in the template file using the long model like this `{% crispy formname formname.helper %}`. I can't use the short version (`{% crispy form %}`) because I have to differentiate between multiple forms. The thing is, all works well for normal forms, but not for a modified Django login form.
The code goes like this:

### forms.py

```
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm

class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'login-form'

        self.helper.form_show_labels = False
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Field('username', placeholder="E-mail"),
            Field('password', placeholder="Password")
        )
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Log in', css_class='btn-block btn-inset'))
```

### views.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login, REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.views import login as django_login
from accounts.forms import LoginForm
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def login(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profiles/create/')
    else:
        response = django_login(request, template_name='accounts/login.html', authentication_form=LoginForm)

        return response
```

When I try to address it in the template in the form of `{% crispy response response.helper %}` I only get an error stating `VariableDoesNotExist at /accounts/whateverurl/: Failed lookup for key [response]`.

How should I address it?

Django 1.6

## EDIT:

The solution works when I want to call the login form from that particular view, but when I try to call it from *profiles/views.py*, not so much.
The *profiles/views.py* looks like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login as auth_login, REDIRECT_FIELD_NAME
from django.contrib.auth.views import login as django_login
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from accounts.forms import LoginForm, RegisterForm
from accounts.views import get_redirect_url

class ProfileView(DetailView):
    model = Profile

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        #lots of irrelevant code#
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            pass
        else:
            login_form = django_login(request, template_name='accounts/login.html', authentication_form=LoginForm).render()
        #lots of irrelevant code#
        context.update({
            #lots of irrelevant code#
            'login_form': login_form,
        })
```

Do I even need to update context for login_form? Anyways, using it like this I get the same `VariableDoesNotExist at /profiles/whateverurl/: Failed lookup for key [form]`.
When I replace `{% crispy form form.helper %}` with `{% crispy login_form login_form.helper %}` I get `VariableDoesNotExist at /profiles/whateverurl/: Failed lookup for key [helper]` instead.

I also tried to clone the working view into *profiles/views.py* and it does work, but only independently. If I `include` the new login view's template into ProfileView's template, it returns the error shown above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django's login view [includes the login form](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.6/django/contrib/auth/views.py#L52) in the template context as `form`. Therefore you should use:

```
{% crispy form form.helper %}
```

Comment: Yes, that makes perfect sense! Thank you very much.
As to why call it response, I couldn't think of anything else to put there except the variable is assigned to it.
What I mean by differentiating between multiple forms is that I have to display 5 or 6 forms in one view and if I call them by `{% crispy form %}`, then every time I'll get the same form.

Comment: If you have multiple forms in a view, then yes, you need to use the correct variable name. In this case, `response` is the http response returned by the `django_login` view, it is not the form that you want to render.

Comment: It appears that it was only half of the solution for me. I updated the original question to describe what goes wrong and where.

Comment: Your `ProfileView` doesn't make sense, it's not clear  what you are actually trying to achieve. As @aiho and I said, `django_login` is a view, it returns an http response. It doesn't make sense to include that in the context of another view as you are doing. It's not a form, so you can't use it with the crispy tag.

Comment: I see. But why is it that when I create an independent view for `django_login`, it works well, but when I include its template into the ProfileView template, it stops working? Shouldn't the separate template be rendered in the same way in every situation?

Comment: The crispy template tag will only work if the required form is in the template context. When you use the template in the `ProfileView`, you have not included the form in the template context, so it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`response = django_login(request, template_name='accounts/login.html', authentication_form=LoginForm)`

is a view, and the form variable in its context is named `form`:

```
context = {
    'form': form,
    ...
}
```

Thus you have to use

```
{% crispy form form.helper %}
```